# how do i transform a spring security configuration from application.groovy to application.yml

Tags: grails, spring-security

Hi all i need to transform this configuration from application.groovy to application.yml

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = 
[   '/':            ['permitAll'],  
'/error':           ['permitAll'],  
'/index':           ['permitAll'],  
'/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],  
'/shutdown':        ['permitAll'],  
'/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],  
'/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],  
'/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],  
'/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],  
'/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'] ]
```

For example 
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.postOnly = false
is represented as

```
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            apf:
                postOnly: false
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            controllerAnnotations:
                staticRules:
                    '/':                permitAll
                    '/error':           permitAll
                    '/index':           permitAll
                    '/index.gsp':       permitAll
                    '/shutdown':        permitAll
                    '/assets/**':       permitAll
                    '/**/js/**':        permitAll
                    '/**/css/**':       permitAll
                    '/**/images/**':    permitAll
                    '/**/favicon.ico':  permitAll
```

It works for me.
YAML specification taken from [official YAML spec website](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963)

Comment: Here's an example with a few more more migrated settings: https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grailstwitter/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.yml

Comment: Thanks @RickyGo. Worked like magic. And the world is back to normal. Thanks Burt Beckwith for the extra settings. I can now continue porting my code Yii PHP framework which by the way appears to have framed after Grails

Comment: Thanks @RickyGo! I'm using Grails 3.1.1 and somehow the application.groovy generated by the plugin under /conf folder has been ignored by my application.

Answer (score 5):

This changed a bit for the 3.0.1 version of the Spring Security plugin for Grails 3.X.  The YML format for 3.0.1 with annotation-based security looks like this:

```
# Added for the Spring Security Core plugin:
---
grails:
  plugin:
    springsecurity :
      userLookup.userDomainClassName: 'org....User'
      userLookup.authorityJoinClassName: 'org....UserRole'
      authority.className: 'org....Role'
      adh.errorPage: '/user/denied'
      controllerAnnotations.staticRules:
        - pattern: '/'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/index'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/index.gsp'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/error'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/user/denied'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/assets/**'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/**/js/**'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/**/css/**'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/**/images/**'
          access: ['permitAll']
        - pattern: '/**/favicon.ico'
          access: ['permitAll']
```